# Android Studio: How to reopen translation window to edit strings?

Tags: android-studio, translation

In Android Studio there's the option for adding a custom translation to the app's strings.
To do this you have to open a layout file and click on the globe icon "Add Translation" over the layout.
How can I reopen that window for editing an existing translation?
I searched for documentation on that, but without results...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To reopen translation window - Right click on `strings.xml` and choose Open Translations Editor.

[image: Open Translations Editor]

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible in current (0.2.5) version :( Only via deleting a re-creating translation.

(via Tor Norbye's answer: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/adt-dev/HEr49_JtII4/6ciEf6mAjZYJ)

Answer (score 1):

On the folder Strings, right button, open translation Editor. In version 3.3.1:

[image: example]